# Get Information About Cylinders, Heads and SPT From CD Image

Tags: windows, iso-image, emulation

I want to boot a CD-ROM image at Bochs, but I need it's cylinders, heads and the Sectors per track. But how I can get this values from the disk image(*.ISO)?

*I'm on Windows, but I have Cygwin installed*

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a CD the number of physical heads is 1 (one), cylinders is 1 (one) and tracks is 1 (one).  I'm assuming you need to lie to some software god to make something work.  Since a sector has 256 bytes, just get the number of sectors by dividing the size of the CD.iso by 256 and make up values for cylinders * heads * spt that equal that number.  It won't matter what you pick as long as the final value of the multiplication is equal to iso_size_in_bytes/256.

Caveat: I'm not a Bochs user (yet) but I'm assuming you want to create a virtual HD to load this iso onto and the Cyl/trk/spt info is going to be used to specify the virtual HD size.

Added: From your data I calculate 583440 sectors, which would give as one possible organization : 2431 cyl, 15 hds, 16 spt.   2431 * 15 * 16 * 256 is 149360640 which equals your iso size.

Comment: No, what I'm trying is a TinyXP disk image. But English isn't my mother language, then it's very difficult to understand you. Could you be more specific? The size of the image is **149.360.640 bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you only need the CHS (cylinders/heads/sectors) counts for disk images. Just be sure to change *Type of ATA device* from `disk` to `cdrom`.